# No suitable constructor found for intent(<anonymous AnimationListener)

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                iv.startAnimation(an2);
                finish();
                Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

I'm having problems with my code on how to put a splash screen.

Comment: Not enough here to understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
```

with

```
Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class); // Use your Splash activity class name
```